# Strip or overwrite an AngularJS $resource

Tags: angularjs, angular-resource

I need to copy data from one resource to another. Problem is that the `$get`, `$save` etc methods on the  old resource remain when wrapping an old resource in a new resource.

### Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/d2oHwm?p=preview

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource'])

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $resource) {

    var ResourceA = $resource('A');

    var ResourceB = $resource('B');

    var instances = {};
    instances.A = new ResourceA({
        label: "Loading..."
    });

    instances.B = new ResourceB(instances.A); // <-- trouble

    instances.B.$get(function() {
        $scope.instances.B = arguments[0]
    });

    $scope.instances = instances;
});
```

I don't want to keep a separate object with the clean data of `ResourceA` because the object can be modified in multiple places. I also rather don't want to write a foreach loop to fetch the pure data.

**Can I get a copy of the pure data in a `ResourceA` without the magic methods? Or is there some other way to ignore/strip/overwrite the magic methods in a resource?**

Background info: A user can create/modify a template (`resourceA`). The user can use that template to create a new object (`ResourceB`). When that happens, the object needs to inherit all properties from the template, except for the `$resource` methods.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do here. Can't you just `instances.B = new ResourceB()`?

Comment: No I cannot do that because ResourceB needs to inherit all properties from ResourceA. Added background info.

Comment: Use `angular.copy`. It will strip angular $-signed properties from the source object: `instances.B = new ResourceB(angular.copy(instances.A));`

Comment: That doesn't work: http://plnkr.co/edit/W9l6fZ?p=preview

Comment: I keep forgetting if it was `angular.toJson` or `angular.copy` that's stripping the "magic" properties. See my answer below ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular.toJson method will strip dollar-prefixed properties from the object. So, this method, in pair with `angular.fromJson`, will provide you with "clean" resource:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['ngResource']);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $resource) {

  var ResourceA = $resource('A');

  var ResourceB = $resource('B');

  var instances = {};
  instances.A = new ResourceA({
      label: "Loading A ..."
  });

  var copy = angular.fromJson(angular.toJson(instances.A));
  instances.B = new ResourceB(copy);

  instances.B.$get(function(response) {
      $scope.instances.B = response;
  });

  $scope.instances = instances;
});
```