# Angular $resources when to use callback functions and how to get the object "clean"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-resource, angularjs-http

I've problem with `$resources` and I didn't really understood when I can simply assign a variable to a `$resource` response `var user = Users.getCurrent()` or when I've to use the callBack.

I created a `service` that it's bound to a `resource`.

```
  .factory('Users', function ($resource, gcAPICOACH) {
    return  $resource(gcAPICOACH + 'users/current',{},
      {
        'getCurrent': {method: 'GET' },
        'save': {method: 'PUT'}

      });
  });
```

I've a service that i use for authorization

```
.factory('gcAuth', function ($rootScope, $log) {
    var currentUser;

    return {
      login: function (user) {
        currentUser = user;
        $rootScope.$emit('notify', {type: 'info', title: gettext('Welcome'), text: user.name});
        $rootScope.$broadcast('user.logged', user,  $rootScope.next);

      },
      isLoggedIn: function () {
        return !angular.isUndefined(currentUser);
      },
      currentUser: function () {
        return currentUser;
      }
    };
  });
```

now I made a simple login controller with login function. **here is the problem, which one should i use?**

```
    $scope.login = function () {
//option 1
      Users.getCurrent(function (user) {
        $log.debug("inside");
        gcAuth.login(user);
      });
//option 2
      gcAuth.login(Users.getCurrent());
    };
```

and the html to call the function:

```
 <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-success" ng-hide="user" ng-click="login()">Login!<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span></a></p>
```

*NOTE: i've interceptors that set the user token, so when i call the `currentUser` it actually returns the correct object*

THe documentation states:

> It is important to realize that invoking a $resource object method immediately returns an empty reference (object or array depending on isArray). Once the data is returned from the server the existing reference is populated with the actual data. This is a useful trick since usually the resource is assigned to a model which is then rendered by the view.

which is clear that for rendering there's no problem, but in this case the "magic" of angular has no effect. Am I correct?

PS: the other problem i've is that the returned object from the `Users.getCurrent()` has also the angular functions such as `$promise` and co. how can i get back a *clean* object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use option 1. `$resource` methods are always async, so it won't return an object immediately, only a *reference* containing an empty placeholder, which gets populated after the ajax call has loaded.

You can get a clean object by using `angular.fromJson(angular.toJson(user))`. Related answered question: [Strip or overwrite an AngularJS $resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20683166/strip-or-overwrite-an-angularjs-resource)